# Why do some biblatex options need to be set in the preamble and cannot be called from a style file using \ExecuteBibliographyOptions?

Tags: biblatex

I personally prefer to set biblatex's package options in a `.bbx` file using `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` so that I can just call biblatex minimally in my preamble (preferably using only `\usepackage[style=myStyle,  natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}`). I noticed however that some options do not work when parsed from the .bbx file using `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` but **must** be supplied in the *preamble* using either `\usepackage` options or `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. In my case I found the following options to cause the problem while others worked fine:

1. labelyear
2. uniquename
3. uniquelist

Of course, I only use a small set of all the possible options so there very well be more options with the same problem.

---

**EDIT - added minimal example**

---

Calling for options from an external `.bbx` file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.bbx}
% Build on the original author-year comp
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear-comp}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    maxcitenames = 2, 
    mincitenames = 1, 
    firstinits = true,
    terseinits = false,
    labelyear=true,  
    uniquename=false, 
    uniquelist=false,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mystyle.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{emi.cbx}[biblatex style for Environmental Microbiology]

\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear-comp}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {Doe, J. and Dane, D., and Dewy, R.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {This and that},
  journal = {Journal of deep understanding of things},
}

@article{ref2,
  author = {Doe, J. and Dewy, D., and Dane, R.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {The other},
  journal = {Journal of deep understanding of things},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=mystyle,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text and a ref \citep{ref1}.
Then another ref with same first author and year \citep{ref2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Produces an undesired output:
[image]

But calling for the same options with `\usepackage` produces the desired output

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {Doe, J. and Dane, D., and Dewy, R.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {This and that},
  journal = {Journal of deep understanding of things},
}

@article{ref2,
  author = {Doe, J. and Dewy, D., and Dane, R.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {The other},
  journal = {Journal of deep understanding of things},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true, 
    maxcitenames = 2, 
    mincitenames = 1, 
    firstinits = true,
    labelyear=true,  
    uniquename=false, 
    uniquelist=false,
    terseinits = false,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text and a ref \citep{ref1}.
Then another ref with same first author and year \citep{ref2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only load-time options can't be set with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. You'll have to demonstrate your problem. The options you mention are set in some of the standard styles without issue.

Comment: According to the biblatex manual (3.1.1) only the following options must be set at load time: style, bibstyle, citestyle, natbib and mcite.

Comment: As of 2+ `backend` should also be in that list. Could've sworn we already made that edit to the manual...

Comment: That was my fault - it was in the wrong doc section for some reason. I've corrected this in the 2.4 beta docs.

Comment: Related [Set biblatex options after loading](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264096/35864)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `cbx` file loads `authoryear-comp.cbx`. This file contains the line

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelyear,uniquename,uniquelist,sortcites,autocite=inline}
```

Since `cbx` files are loaded after `bbx`, the option settings in your style's `bbx` file get overwritten. To resolve the problem, move your option settings to the `cbx` file, after `\RequireCitationStyle`.