# Set biblatex options after loading

Tags: biblatex, packages, package-options

I use `biblatex` with the following call:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
  mergedate=false,
  maxcitenames=1, 
  mincitenames=1, 
  maxbibnames=999, 
  minbibnames=999, 
  uniquename=false,
  uniquelist=minyear,
  ibidtracker=context,
  labeldate=true,
  hyperref=true,
  isbn=false,
  dashed=false,
  eprint=false,
  doi=false,
  url=true]{biblatex}
```

However, because of some templating reasons (*) I want to set the package options separately **after** I load the package. So I wnat to do something like this:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

and then later (but still before the `\begin{document}`):

```
\setbiblatexoptions[style=authoryear,
  mergedate=false,
  maxcitenames=1, 
  mincitenames=1, 
  maxbibnames=999, 
  minbibnames=999, 
  uniquename=false,
  uniquelist=minyear,
  ibidtracker=context,
  labeldate=true,
  hyperref=true,
  isbn=false,
  dashed=false,
  eprint=false,
  doi=false,
  url=true]
```

How can I do this?

---

(*) The tex file is created by `pandoc` from a markdown document; `pandoc` uses a template system wheer the main template already contains a plain call to `\usepackage{biblatex}` while the local customisations are inserted later (just before the `\begin{document}`). In these customisations I can easily add biblatex options or I could even reload the  package with the `style=authoryear` option if this were possible.

Comment: Imho you can set all your options with the exception of `style=authoryear` with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`.

Comment: All options except those listed in §3.1.1 *Load-time Options* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) can be passed to `biblatex` with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. The load-time options are `(cite/bib)style`, `backend`, `natbib`, `mcite`.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise what exactly you want to be able to do?

Comment: @moewe I have added some details as a footnote to the question. Hope this helps!

Comment: You will have to set the `style` when loading `biblatex` and it cannot be changed afterwards. You will have to change your template appropriately. (Which seems possible [here](http://blog.twshodgson.co.uk/2014/12/12/pandoc-biblatex-citeproc-hs-languages-and-names/)) See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208296/35864

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have now written up a short answer. If you want to add an answer yourself I will happily delete mine.

Comment: @moewe it's fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of the many options available for `biblatex`, there are only very few that have to be set at loading time in the square brackets, all others can also be used with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` later in the preamble.

These exceptions are listed in §3.1.1 *Load-time Options*, p. 44-45 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). They are

- `backend`,
- `style`, `bibstyle` and `citestyle`,
- and the `natbib` and `mcite` compatibility options.

The other options listed in §3.1.2 *Preamble Options*, pp. 45-60, can be used in `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` later on.

Answer (score 2):

With the command `\PassOptionsToPackage`, you can choose options *before* loading the package for the first time: if necessary even before your `\documentclass` preamble, in case that is where the package is loaded.

Example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage[style=authoryear,
                      mergedate=false,
                      maxcitenames=1, 
                      mincitenames=1, 
                      maxbibnames=999, 
                      minbibnames=999, 
                      uniquename=false,
                      uniquelist=minyear,
                      ibidtracker=context,
                      labeldate=true,
                      hyperref=true,
                      isbn=false,
                      dashed=false,
                      eprint=false,
                      doi=false,
                      url=true]{biblatex}
\documentclass{article}
…
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

To my understanding, it adds to the option list, it does not override further options.

More info [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-optionclash.html). Adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272600/17145).

Comment: Isn't the point of the question to set options after the package is loaded?