# When/How should a class load biblatex

Tags: biblatex, documentclass-writing, package-options

I would like to write a custom class that loads the `biblatex` package, but I am having trouble with option clashes. For example, the following MWE gives me an error

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2015/12/29 My MWE class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber}{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package biblatex.

The error is pretty clear. The class loads biblatex with the `backend=biber` option and then again in the document with the `backend=biber` and `authoryear` options.

I tried making the class only load the biblatex package with the `\AtBeginDocument` hook (and the `\AtEndPreamble` hook from the etoolbox package) if it is not loaded in the preamble.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{}{\RequirePackage{biblatex}}}
```

This apparently is too late to load the biblatex package. The only way I can get it to work is to patch the `\document` macro

```
\preto{\document}{\endgroup\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{}{\RequirePackage{biblatex}\begingroup}}{}{}
```

How should a class load the biblatex package?

Comment: Untested: I think you should define options that are really passed to `biblatex`.

Comment: Don't do `\RequirePackage{biblatex}` in the class.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but the user would then need to do `\PassOptionsToPackage{biblatex}{...}` prior to `\documentclass` which seems strange.

Comment: @egreg so I cannot have a class that provides the biblatex package? The user needs to specify it?

Comment: By the way, `biber` is the default back-end

Comment: @StrongBad: No, I meant `\documentclass[authoryear]{myclass}`, i.e. something that is not handled by `article` (which is the effective class in the background) is then passed to `biblatex`. The user should load `biblatex` then.

Comment: You can specify options to `biblatex` with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` in the document preamble.

Comment: @egreg: A `biblatexsetup` like `\hypersetup` would be nice, however. Joseph should be poked about this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it has one, but the documentation says it cannot handle the backend or style as those have to be loadtime.

Comment: @StrongBad: Really? Well I don't use `bibliography` stuff very often.

Comment: Related: [Set biblatex options after loading](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264096/35864) has a list of loading-time options, all others can be set with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to add an option to the class to suppress loading the biblatex package in the class. This gives a default of loading biblatex with the default values, but if the user wants to manually load biblatex, then they need to provide the class option.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2015/12/29 My MWE class]
\newif\ifnobiblatex
\DeclareOption{nobiblatex}{\nobiblatextrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber}{biblatex}
\ifnobiblatex%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{}
    {\ClassError{myclass}{Fatal: biblatex not loaded}
       {You must load biblatex, I'll end here}\@@end}%
}
\else\RequirePackage{biblatex}\fi
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[nobiblatex]{myclass}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, `style=...` can only be given in the optional argument to `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`, so if you want to leave the authors free to choose the style they prefer you cannot load `biblatex` in the class.

What you can do is to specify the options you *do* want:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2015/12/29 My MWE class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber}{biblatex}
\endinput
```

I tried and, specifying `backend=bibtex` in the document is ineffective. You could also add a fatal error:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2015/12/29 My MWE class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber}{biblatex}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{}
    {\ClassError{myclass}{Fatal: biblatex not loaded}
       {You must load biblatex, I'll end here}\@@end}%
}
\endinput
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trial solution with `\DeclareOption{authoryear}{...}` (for example)

Make sure to use `\LoadClassWithOptions{...}` before `\DeclareOption`, otherwise `myclass` will complain about `authoryear`.

More sophisticated approaches require a better option handling of course, especially the option values.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2015/12/29 My MWE class]
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\DeclareOption{authoryear}{\PassOptionsToPackage{style=authoryear}{biblatex}}
\ProcessOptions
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[authoryear]{myclass}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Lam94}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a huge number of styles and not all are known to the class writer.

Comment: @StrongBad: That's true, of course. Perhaps, it's really not the best idea to load this huge package `biblatex` by the class already (or trying to provide option wrappers)